# Reaction Listener in discord.py

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

Okay, so I would like to make some kind of listener/watcher(?), that would track amount of reactions added to message. Should I make it as an async function (asyncio task?) or maybe there is better and more simple(?) solution. I would like it to track those reactions until specific amount of them. Would really appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put something to this effect in your code. It will fire whenever a reaction is added while the bot is running.

```
@bot.listen()
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    # do something with reaction and user
```

or, if you're using `discord.Client`,

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    # do something with reaction and user
```

I recommend looking at the documentation, which I will link, to see what things you can do with this, but to give you a head start, you can get the message itself using `reaction.message` and from there (since you mentioned counting reactions) get the full list of reactions with `reaction.message.reactions`.

[`on_reaction_add` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add)
[`Reaction` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction)
[`Message` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message)